# IIOT OPCUA Alarms and Events node-red

Tags: node.js, iot, node-red, opc-ua, node-opcua

I am working on OPC DA & AE. For that, I am using the IIOT OPCUA node in Node-red.
With the IIOT OPCUA node in Node-red I am able to connect and access data but for accessing the alarms and events not getting what to do.
I have tested my OPCAE server with the OPC expert tool and it's working fine but I want to execute alarms and events with Node-red.
Please help me out regarding this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t worked with alarms and events yet but you or other people interessted may have a look on [this discusion](https://github.com/mikakaraila/node-red-contrib-opcua/issues/402).

OPCUA-TEST-NODES.json contains an examples for testing events:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Test Nodes",
        "disabled": false
    },
    {
        "id": "42ce521b1148624d",
        "type": "OpcUa-Event",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "root": "ns=0;i=2253",
        "eventtype": "i=2041",
        "name": "Events",
        "x": 570,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": [
            [
                "59e10624d8d6798b",
                "7bc93ab21da004f4"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "50afc9882c32c9b1",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "Test Events",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": "",
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "x": 370,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": [
            [
                "42ce521b1148624d"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "59e10624d8d6798b",
        "type": "OpcUa-Client",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "endpoint": "bb039652.dcf5a8",
        "action": "events",
        "deadbandvalue": "",
        "time": 10,
        "timeUnit": "s",
        "localfile": "",
        "localkeyfile": "",
        "securitymode": "None",
        "securitypolicy": "None",
        "folderName4PKI": "",
        "name": "A & C",
        "x": 730,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": [
            [
                "47d20f3e7618f5db"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9598544e1e208e0c",
        "type": "OpcUa-Client",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "endpoint": "bb039652.dcf5a8",
        "action": "acknowledge",
        "deadbandtype": "a",
        "deadbandvalue": "5",
        "time": "1",
        "timeUnit": "s",
        "localfile": "",
        "localkeyfile": "",
        "securitymode": "None",
        "securitypolicy": "None",
        "name": "ProSys NONE",
        "x": 1060,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "47d20f3e7618f5db",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "x": 890,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "9a7458deff86b3b0",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "Test Events",
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "x": 370,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            [
                "d02ed4a7087a2cd8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "d02ed4a7087a2cd8",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "AlarmID and EventID",
        "func": "var msg;\nmsg.topic = \"ns=6;s=MyLevel.Alarm\";\nmsg.conditionId = \"ns=6;s=MyLevel.Alarm/0:EventId\";\nmsg.comment = \"Node-RED OPCUA Ack\";\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "x": 630,
        "y": 580,
        "wires": [
            [
                "9598544e1e208e0c"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7bc93ab21da004f4",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "x": 730,
        "y": 440,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "bb039652.dcf5a8",
        "type": "OpcUa-Endpoint",
        "endpoint": "opc.tcp://H7Q8Q13.vstage.co:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer",
        "secpol": "None",
        "secmode": "None",
        "login": false
    }
]
    {
        "id": "7bc93ab21da004f4",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "6413368d70ce7daa",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "x": 730,
        "y": 440,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "bb039652.dcf5a8",
        "type": "OpcUa-Endpoint",
        "endpoint": "opc.tcp://H7Q8Q13.vstage.co:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer",
        "secpol": "None",
        "secmode": "None",
        "login": false
    },
    {
        "id": "85144921.8931b8",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "OPCUA",
        "tab": "440c46c6.769ab8",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "6",
        "collapse": false
    },
    {
        "id": "440c46c6.769ab8",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Home",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```